# Does Tomcat Session requires user to sign in?

Tags: tomcat

Does session requires the user to sign to generate?  Or there is always a session id when using Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 'tomcat session'. Tomcat is just a servlet container. Sessions are implemented by frameworks deployed in tomcat, such as Spring, or by Tomcat's implementation of the JSP standard. There's no requirement for any sort of login with JSP sessions. If you ask for a session, it will make a session ID.